# C# iterate resources subdirectories

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm adding some embedded resources to a project, each in their own sub directory, but I'm going to have to add about 50 sub directories, or so.

What I'd like to do is to have the program iterate through each of the sub directories, and then do stuff with the files contained within them, using the directory name as a part of the process.  I'm trying to avoid having to write 50 of;

```
foreach (var resourceFile in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Where(x => x.Contains("SubDirectoryName")))
```

I can't seem to find a way of looping through the directories, without resorting to substring manipulation, is there a built in way to do this?

Comment: There are no "subdirectories" in the resources. The data will be stored "flat". The only way is to sort the resources using their names. You can create your own helper classes for that.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case.  I guess the subdirectories are something that visual studio adds.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to create sub directory according to the resources and put the resources to the sub directory.

You can refer to the following code example.

```
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\sample");
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                string name = Path.GetFileName(item);
                string path = "D:\\new";
                string newpath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
                File.Copy(item, Path.Combine(newpath, name));
                Console.WriteLine(filename);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Note: All the resource files come from D:\sample and the code will create the sub

directory in the path of D:\new. Finally, the code will copy these source files to the

sub directory.

Hope it can help you.